# Can't Enable QueryBuilder for Outlook 2019

Tags: outlook, regedit

I've followed the instruction from [here](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/using-query-builder/) to enable QueryBuilder in Outlook 2019.
In RegEdit I didn't found  the "Outlook key" in that path, but I created it anyway, together with the "QueryBuilder" key.

Even though I've restart my PC, the QueryBuilder tab on Advanced Filter and on Search Folder won't show up.
What am I missing?

Edit:Just to be more specific, I need to enable the QueryBuilder on a corporate PC with a domain user logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a week of googling, I've finally find the solution:
You must add the "QueryBuilder" key as current user and NOT with admin privileges. In this way I was able to get the Query Builder on Outlook on my corporate PC.

Comment: I am not able to add keys to the Outlook settings if I run regedit using current user privileges. As an admin I can but it has no effect in Outlook.

Comment: Solved it: Some article used this 
*incorrect* address: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook`. Confusingly the sub structure is the same, but the actual one is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\office\16.0\outlook` without the `Policies` subdir. This works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the Query Builder option in OutLook, use one of the following two commands. The first one is to be ran from a **Command Prompt** that is running with **Admin** privileges, the second command is to be ran from a **PowerShell Prompt** that is running with **Admin** privileges.

Both commands are intended for **OutLook 2016/2019/2021**. If you have an older version of OutLook, substitute the registry key in the commands with one of the values listed below that matches your version of OutLook (*just change the version number*):

- **Outlook 2013** : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook
- **Outlook 2010** : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook
- **Outlook 2007** : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook
- **Outlook 2003** : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Outlook
- **Outlook 2002** : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\10.0\Outlook

**Command Prompt command:**

```
Reg Add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\QueryBuilder
```

**PowerShell Prompt command:**

```
New-Item -Path HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook -Name QueryBuilder -Force
```

If the registry key does not get created, it means you did not run the command as **Administrator**.

Tested on Windows 10/11.

Comment: This procedure works only when your user is an Admininistrator. In my case I have a domain user with no Admin rights.
So to be able to active the QueryBuilder in a domain PC, you have to add that key as the current user logged-in. Otherwise it won't work.